# ROSJAVA org.ros.internal.message cannot be cast to std_msgs.String

Tags: java, eclipse, casting, client, ros

I'm working recently with Rosjava Kinetic and I have some problems and doubts. I have imported the project to Eclipse to mix it with another project that I have, called PELEA, composed of several modules, to make the message passing through a client-server. Of course, I have a terminal running roscore and a server running inside eclipse. I make the new client and the new message in this way:

```
public void onStart(final ConnectedNode connectedNode) {

ServiceClient<std_msgs.String, std_msgs.String> serviceClient;

try {
     serviceClient = connectedNode.newServiceClient("custom_service", std_msgs.String._TYPE); 
} catch (ServiceNotFoundException e) {
          throw new RosRuntimeException(e);
}

 final std_msgs.String request = serviceClient.newMessage(); //ERROR!!
 request.setData("Hello");  

 serviceClient.call(request, new ServiceResponseListener<std_msgs.String>() {

      @Override
    public void onSuccess(std_msgs.String response) {
    connectedNode.getLog().info(String.format("The response is: "));
                response.getData();}
    @Override
    public void onFailure(org.ros.exception.RemoteException e) {
    throw new RosRuntimeException(e);
    }
  });
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-3" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ros.internal.message.$Proxy4 cannot be cast to std_msgs.String
at org.squeleton.executiondeclarative.ExecutionSqueleton.clientManagement(ExecutionSqueleton.java:591)
at org.squeleton.executiondeclarative.Client.onStart(Client.java:57)
at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode$5.run(DefaultNode.java:507)
at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode$5.run(DefaultNode.java:504)
at org.ros.concurrent.EventDispatcher.loop(EventDispatcher.java:43)
at org.ros.concurrent.CancellableLoop.run(CancellableLoop.java:56)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

So.. I don't know what is the problem, I think it should works..

I appreciate any help, advide or guide.

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad english.